# Imageresizer watermark - changing the image

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I have watermarks working fine using asp.net imageresizer but I want to be able to set the watermark image via an admin function.

The image path is set in the web.config, but if I overwrite this image the watermark does not change - it always shows the old image unless I change the web.config. So obviously it is being cached - how can get it to return the image with the new watermark file?

I have tried touching the file that has the watermark applied, touching the watermark file itself - nothing works unless I change the web.config which is not feasible for a live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watermark overlays are memory-cached for best performance - thus no disk check. The Watermark plugin can be reconfigured via C# - so if you need to dynamically change watermark data, I'd suggest doing it that way, rather than overwriting the file. It's a new image, so change the filename. That will also ensure that cached results with outdated overlays/watermarks are updated immediately.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I ended up doing and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue, by creating a new image and dynamically setting the 'path' for the named layer.

```
    public static void SetWatermarkFile(string layername, string filename)
    {
        var wp = ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins.Get<ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.WatermarkPlugin>();
        var named = wp.NamedWatermarks[layername];
        ((ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.ImageLayer)((ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.Layer[])named)[0]).Path = WatermarkFilesPath + "/" + filename;
    }
```